# VBA - Finding, cutting, and pasting to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a check in/out system for tools. So far I have a worksheet that has a list of items that are checked out currently. Column A in that worksheet is the item number, Column B is the name, and Column C is the date and time. The macro I am trying to make is that when someone enters an the item number they want to check back IN, the macro will find that number they enter on the "Items Out" sheet, cut the entire row, and paste it to the "checkout History" sheet on the first available row. The cell that the user inputs the number they are checking in is the cell "E3" on the "Interface" worksheet. This is what I have so far.

```
Sub Checkin()
'
    Dim targetSh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 6).value = Worksheets("Interface").Range("E3") Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Copy Worksheets("Items Out").Range("A" & Worksheets("Checkout History").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This doesn't work, I got this code from another post and I tried to change it to match my needs but it did not work and I could use some help here. You don't need to make the entire macro unless you really want to, I just need help finding what will make this macro work for me!

Comment: You should always specify what doesn't work exactly. Do you get an error message? Does the macro do something unexpected? Does Excel crash?  Does Excel not respond? etc. That said, you don't specify the sheets so you copy from the active worksheet. It is recommended that you always specify the sheet for `Range` and `Cells` the way you are doing in the target of the `.Copy`. 2. Thing: You copy to the sheet "Items Out" but take the last row from the sheet "Checkout History".

Comment: You also don't use `targetSh`

Comment: I'm lost at the section `Worksheets("items Out").Range("A" & ...` What are you trying to do there?